# set difference operation in sql

Tags: sql

if i perform set difference between two sets A and B( A and B are union compatible) A has 4 cols and 20 rows and B has 4 cols and 15 rows.what will be the no rows and cols in result

Comment: Depends on the data in those rows.

Comment: Why don't you set up a couple of database tables and figure it out with a query. This is not a do your homework site. If you don't understand databases, then you will never be a competent developer, so get offyour buitt and learn it instead of expecting other people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `UNION`, the duplicates are removed so when all the records in all the 4 columns are same then then you will get only one row as result.

If you don't have any duplicate rows then totally 35 records will be resulted. When I say duplicate it means all the 4 columns are same in more than one row.

---

In case of `SET` difference

When all the 15 records in B table is present in A table then 0 records will be resulted

When all the 15 records in B table is not present in A table then all 15 records will be resulted

When some x records in B table is not present in A table then x records will be resulted

Comment: This isn't quite set difference. It's quite the opposite.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - Updated for set difference

Comment: Great! Btw, I didn't -1 I actually +1ed just now.